# Tcl 8.5 Wish.exe spawns two windows (console + another window)

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I just built tcl 8.5 from the sources provided and I'm starting a wish85/wish process.

Two windows are spawned, one of them being the actual console.

I want to know how to force this behavior: closing the console should close the process.
I tried to force a handler for the WM_DELETE_WINDOW message but it doesn't seem to work.

Can you guys help?

Comment: The console usually doesn't show up when you're running an application, only when you start it as a shell.  Do you want the console to always show up with your application?

Comment: Yes, the console should always show up. My problem is that the closing the console doesn't close the whole process (wish85.exe).

Answer (score 2):

The console window runs in a different interp, so you have to install the protocol handler there. A way to do that is with

```
console eval {wm protocol . WM_DELETE_WINDOW exit}
```

The console implementation is in `[file join $tk_library console.tcl]` (on my system C:/Tcl/lib/tk8.6/console.tcl), if you want to mess around there (not recommended).